# C# String.Format and SpriteBatch.DrawString spacing issues

Tags: c#, string, xna, formatting, drawing

I have strings formatted using the code below

```
String.Format("{0,-10} {1,10}", "Kills:", kills);
String.Format("{0,-10} {1,10}", "Points:", points);
String.Format("{0,-10} {1,10}", "$:", currency);
```

From what I understood, the first part of the strings should be left justified with a 10 space buffer and then the integer variables should be printed right justified with a 10 space buffer.

However when attempt to draw the strings using SpriteBatch.DrawString, nothing aligns properly.

The left aligned side prints properly, but the right aligned side centres on a certain point, for example if kills = 50 and points = 5002, the 50 will be centered over the 00 in the 5002...

What is going on?

Comment: That would work if it was rendered with a fixed pitch font where every character takes the same amount of space.  That's however low odds if you don't control SpriteFont explicitly.  It isn't clear if you do so you probably don't.  Not very pretty either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, I suspect you're not using a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). When different characters have different widths, you can't use spaces to line things up. (Your sample works when using `Console.WriteLine` for example, as the console has a fixed width font by default.)

You'll *either* have to use a monospaced font, *or* you'll have to draw the strings separately - draw each string to fit the relevant area. I don't know anything about XNA, but I'd expect you to either have to measure the width of the string before you draw it (so you can subtract it from the right-hand edge, for example) or specify some sort of layout value which indicates "right-align this string with a particular point".

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you draw the text with a *proportional* font. Bear in mind that **characters don't have the same width**, so you cannot align texts with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have reply privileges, (or some such thing, as there is no reply button for answers), but I would like to contribute, I will post this answer.

Jon's answer mentioned measuring the string, this is possible by `spriteFont.MeasureString(string s);`. This returns a Vector2, the X portion of which is the width of the rendered text. (Y is height, which could be helpful for other things) This allows you to use a font other than a monospace font.

Here is an example of using `MeasureString`:

I'm not really sure what the question is asking, but if you wanted a single line of text similar to "Kills:50 Points:5002" but width two different spritebatch calls you could do the following (note I typed this directly into stackoverflow, so there may be minor syntax errors):

```
    float killStringWidth = spriteFont.MeasureString(killString).X;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, killString, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White );
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, pointString, new Vector2(killStringWidth + 10, 0), Color.White );
```